# PSN+ on all profiles on same console?

Tags: ps3, psn

Please tell me that Sony doesn't expect me to pay for full subscriptions per account just to enable backing up game data to the cloud?

I just got a subscription just so me and my family won't have to worry about losing our game data. But when I go to enable PSN+ backups of save data on accounts other than mine, it asks me to sign up for PSN+.

So PSN+ isn't console-wide?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the benefits of PSN+, such as the free games and overnight updates, benefit the other accounts. However, PSN+ cloud access is only allowed by the master account of the console. (See [here](http://community.us.playstation.com/thread/3417623?start=0&tstart=0).)